# UNPIVOT Display Column Names

Tags: sql, t-sql

Creating a Report for somebody using a SQL Database that is poorly designed and archaic.

My code is presently

```
SELECT B@, PolRef@ , [Document Status]
FROM
(
  SELECT chas.B@, chas.PolRef@, chas.P_asdecl, chas.P_gap, chas.P_acl
  FROM dbo.ic_BD_CHAS chas
) AS chas
UNPIVOT 
(
  [Document Status] FOR DocStatus IN (P_asdecl, P_gap, P_acl)
) AS up;
```

All 3 columns "chas.P_asdecl, chas.P_gap, chas.P_acl" display the same information either 'Not Required' or 'Outstanding'. My output is presently:

```
B@          PolRef@    Document Status
----------- ---------- ---------------
0           AACX02PC01 Not Required
0           AACX02PC01 Not Required
```

The issue here is I have NOT IDEA which column those 2 returned 'Not Required' rows relate to. How can I add a further column pertaining to which column those values come from so essentially my output would be like:

```
B@          PolRef@    Column     Document Status
----------- ---------- --------   ---------------
0           AACX02PC01 P_asdecl   Not Required
0           AACX02PC01 P_gap      Not Required
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your first line query to:

`SELECT B@, PolRef@ , DocStatus, [Document Status]`

Comment: That easy? Feel like a fool now.